# Post Comment in FB without showing name and DP

Tags: facebook

First of all I apologize for posting such question, I knows its not the platform for asking such questions.
I saw a post on Facebook,I saw a comment on it, with no username and display pic. Everyone was wondering How did he/she do that. I am curious to know how to post comment without showing name and display pic.
I am unable to attach its screen shot :(

Answer (score 0):

the comment must be made by a page without a name. you can also make a page without a name. 
first make a page,
 edit and remove its name from settings.
now whenever you will comment, no name will be shown.